# Separate unique and common nested structures across nested dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I will have N different nested dictionaries where the different nested structures will have varying depth.

```
 d1 = {'A' : {'B' : 1, 'C': {'D' : 2 } } }

 d2 = {'A' : {'C' : {'D' : 2 } , 'E' : 3, 'F' : { 'G' : {'H' : 3 } } } }

 ..
```

What I want to do, is separate any common and unique structrures across ALL dictionaries.

What would be an efficient way of doing this?

If we would think that only d1 and d2 I would want the output to be

```
common_d = {'A' : { 'C' : {'D' : 2 } } }

unique_d1 = {'A' : {'B' : 1 } }
unique_d2 = {'A' : {'E' : 3, 'F' : { 'G' : {'H' : 3 } } } }
```

Would there be any way of doing this for N nested dictionaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have hierarchical (nested) dictionary values,
with identifiers along each path from root down to leaf.
Turn such paths into something hashable,
such as `tuple` or `str`,
and throw them into a `set` that describes d1.

Now iterate similarly over d2 and compute set intersection,
noting any d2 paths that also appeared in d1.
If you store sorted sets in text files,
you will find they offer informative `diff` output.

Or just traverse d1's paths and probe d2
with similar path as you go.

Comment: Thank you, and if I have d3, d4. Surely it would be possible to iterate one by one, and compute set intersection of the past calculated set intersection?

Comment: If you throw those paths into sets, you could even do something like `s1 & s2 & s3 & s4`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection

Comment: That's really smart. Is there a similarly easy way to remove said set intersection from one of the dictionaries? To separate the unique paths? 

Like d1 - (d1 & d2)

Comment: Well, if you read that doc, it offers set `difference` and `symmetric_difference`. Then whatever set you settle on, iterate through it to pick out keys and values from your favorite dict. Also, recall that you can say `del d[k]` to nuke key `k`.